# Null response using $.getJson() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have been trying to get a response from a server sending a GET URL, but isn't working for this particular server, on the other hand, when I put the same GET URL in the browser I obtain an answer. The server is in django python and I don't have access, because I'm currently programming the client side.

This is the javascript code:

```
var url = "https://www.mysite.com/module/get_requ/?user=ms&money_type=F&coin-count=1&pass=test&slots_id=12&line-value=9&slots_type=12&cacheBuster=1278933269465&coin-value=0.05";  
$.getJSON(url,  
        function(data){  
            alert(data);  
        });
```

but when i do:

```
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=jso&jsoncallback=?";
```

In the above code it work perfect. So, I want to know if i'm doing something wrong, or the problem is in the server side.

Comment: Are the server and client code in the same domain? You cannot make a request to another domain due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: looks like a simple typo ... you're passing 'url_flickr' to the getJSON command, but you set `var url`. (assuming it works for the second url you provide since that is a a flickr url ... is the code above a direct copy paste?

Comment: @chakram88, sorry about that, im passing `url` in the original code, i have the `url` and `url_flickr` vars in the original code.  

@Andrew Whitaker, i'm making the request from my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  The flicker api uses JSONP, which is not subject to the SOP.  So, unless bingocastle.co.uk also exposes a JSONP interface, you will not be able to request data from bingocastle.co.uk client side, without going through some server proxy.